# Stock list table - minimum amount - if else

Tags: jquery, if-statement, html-table, import-from-csv

I have a stock list in a .csv file and I am using a CSV to table plugin in Joomla to view all the data.

What the plugin creates is that..

```
<table class="arttable_table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="header0">Aricle</th>
      <th class="header1">amount</th><th class="header2">minimum amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell0">Coffee</td>
      <td class="cell1">5</td>
      <td class="cell2">10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell0">Milk</td>
      <td class="cell1">7</td>
      <td class="cell2">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="cell0">Bread</td>
      <td class="cell1">8</td>
      <td class="cell2">15</td>
    </tr>
  <!-- ... and so on! -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The only thing I would like to do is: 
If the amount is smaller than the minimum amount, make the amount background red. The problem is that the classes repeat. So I can not just say:

```
if (parseInt($(".cell1").text()) < parseInt($(".cell2").text())) {
    $(".cell1").addClass("red");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a loop?

```
$('.cell1').each(function() {
  if ( parseInt($(this).text()) < parseInt($(this).siblings(".cell2").text()) ) {
    $(this).addClass("red");
  }
})
```

Comment: @AndrewJackson `filter` function is more handy since you then have the filtered list of cells on which you could perform other actions if needed

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method:

```
$('.cell1').filter(function() {
    return parseInt($(this).text()) < parseInt($(this).next('.cell2').text());
}).addClass('red');
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrZMy/)